# The partitions on the disk selected for installation are not in the recommended order

Tags: windows-7, installation

I receive this message when I try to install Windows 7 on a GPT Disk

> The partitions on the disk selected for installation are not in the recommended order. For additional information about installing to GPT disks go to the Microsoft website (www.microsoft.com) and search for GPT.
>   Do you want to proceed with installation?

Is it safe to click on **Yes** and proceed with the installation? I have UEFI on my laptop, it is SAMSUNG 300E4C/300E5C/300E7C.

Comment: Are you installing on top of the old operating system? Is the disk already formatted? If you don't care about the contents of the HD, you could manually format it and wipe the partition table to get rid of that message.

Comment: @LeeHarrison Yes, I'm installing from my Windows 8 OS, I do not really want to wipe the HDD. Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you are installing onto a "clean" disk with no valuable data, the worst that it can do is fail to install. If it installs and works, cool, you're good to go. If not, you can try to fix it.

Now, I've found some other people [on a mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/ntsysadmin@lyris.sunbelt-software.com/msg111504.html) who are apparently puzzled by this same problem. Their solution was, in order to play it safe, they wiped the entire hard disk (using a partition utility) and let the Windows Installer create the partitions in the order it wanted them in. This made the error message go away.

So you have two options:

1. Try it. If it works, you can forget about the problem. If it breaks, you'll end up doing the next step anyway:
2. Just wipe the entire disk clean (delete all partitions and/or re-initialize the partition table) using a tool such as Gparted, sysresccd, or a Linux live CD. You might even be able to use a Windows PE environment if you insist on not using non-Microsoft tools.

Comment: I've just tried doing this from Windows 8, I noticed that I need to turn off the secure boot option in the BIOS so I did and proceeded with the installation. After copying files it restarted the PC to complete the next step of the setup, but now it is just stuck at Starting Windows and the Windows logo.

Comment: Ack. Didn't know you had Secure Boot enabled. Hopefully you didn't brick your system. There are lots of issues with Samsung UEFI laptops and secure boot that can cause it to be bricked, even if running Windows!

Comment: Also, you probably can't install Windows 7 "on top of" Windows 8 without losing all your files, especially since Secure Boot was enabled before. Back up your data and start over fresh.

Comment: I think this is the answer. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 3):

1. I also got the same alert/prompt while installing Windows 7 on a GPT disk, to make it a dual boot with pre-installed Windows 8 (on a laptop with single internal disk), but I went ahead because all the things were in right order and I realized the equation can never be satisfied while making a dual boot on a single GPT disk with no problems ever.
2. The ideal/recommended order is mentioned [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-7/dd744301%28v%3Dws.10%29) - let's see what it says:

   - If you make the GPT disk unallocated & then proceed with the installation, you will end with this structure:
     [image: Default Configuration]
   - But preferably, you should plan this structure to make the Recovery easier: [image: Recommended Configuration]

     - The Recommended structure requires some extra steps and is followed in OEM Laptops
3. One will not be able to satisfy the equation for a dual boot ever on the same internal disk (see above) because a data partition should come in between the main Windows partition & Recovery Image partition. When you attempt to make a dual boot, you are planning two adjacent windows partitions, which will each look to the other as data partitions. The previously installed OS satisfies the equation, but the latter installed OS has a data partition placed before it, and I think that's the problem.
4. There's a separate link for [Win 10](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions), but I think there is a mistake within the link and image:
   [image: Win 10 GPT Config]

   - It seems wrong because it puts **Recovery partition (WinRE)** after **Windows** partition & doesn't mention **Recovery Image** partition at all!

     - The **WinRE tools** partition which comes at the first place in **Win 7/8 GPT config** share same **Type ID:** **`de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac`** with the **Recovery partition** that comes after **Windows** in the **Win 10 GPT config** as per the text of the links.
     - How we can we confirm the mistake? I have OEM laptops shipped with win 7/8 with GPT. They came originally configured as per the link for Win7 /8. 
        **But...** I have never come across an OEM laptop shipped with win 10 with GPT with original OEM config. Do you have one?
5. The **Win 10 GPT config** link also says about the partition order (leaving **Recovery** & **Recovery Image** Partition) that the **non-Windows managed utility partition(s)** should follow **EFI** & **MSR** partitions & **Windows**, with **Data** partition(s) following thereafter.

   - **Partition Order:** EFI, MSR, Non-Windows managed utility, Windows, Data

     - *I think it should be exactly followed in the **Win 7/8 GPT** config as well.*
     - *It also seems obvious that **Recovery Image** Partition, if any, should serve as the last Partition on the disk, after **Data Partition(s).** So, where the **Recovery (WinRE Tools)** Partition in **Win 10 GPT Config**?*

Comment: @JW0914 : Fine work sir. Thanks.

Comment: I am a little confused by the term ''Non Windows Managed Utilities'' & feel that it holds / refers to ''Recovery Partition''. Then the order for Win 7/8/10 GPT partitions should be : Recovery Partition, EFI, MSR,Windows, Data Partition(s) & Recovery Image partition!

Comment: I am submitting this comment to nearly every one of your answers.  We do not consider greetings, salutations, or signatures to be helpful.  So please avoid using this in your answers in the future.  Specifically with regards to this answer, even after numerous revisions, it had numerous grammatical mistakes.  Please take a moment and use the appropriate tools to avoid that issue in the future.  Contributions that have numerous grammatical mistakes often will result in a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly likely going to be fine.  As stated by some other answers, this can be rather easy to handle so that more people can satisfy Microsoft Windows and not have the warning pop up.

However, having the partitions in the wrong order is not typically going to be a critical issue.  The reason why it can be desirable to have partitions in a certain order is so that some partitions may be able to be resized more easily, by cannibalizing space in other partitions.  In particular, the partitions for special purposes (System partition, Recovery partition, and MSR partition) may often have quite a bit of free space.  It seems like Microsoft was initially unsure about how much data they would like to store in such partitions over time.  As it turns out, the answer ended up being: not much.

None of which will matter if you don't end up resizing partitions.  (And even if you do find a need to re-size partitions and it can't be done easily, you're still looking at a task that can be done reasonably easily through backup, re-partitioning, and restoring.)  So for typical day-to-day usage, this doesn't pose a particularly worrying significant threat to data, or other such catastrophic concerns.