# Is the 100MB partition in Windows 7-Win10 , there regardless of whether the drive's partition table is MBR or GPT?

Tags: windows

I have a question regarding the 100MB partition in Windows7 - Windows10

Is the 100MB partition in Windows 7-Win10 , there regardless of whether the drive's partition table is MBR or GPT?

Comment: I deleted my answer as you have said I do not understand. Your question simply asked to the systems have the same small partitions and I tried to answer that.

Comment: @John you understood the question you just didn't understand my comment about WinRE

Answer (score 1):

There are two different partitions that you might be talking about (System and MSR). Windows 7-10 use a "System" partition which contains the boot manager. Having the boot manager on a separate partition makes it so that the operating system partition can be encrypted (using Bitlocker), and the boot manager (on the non-encrypted system partition) can unlock the operating system partition (decrypt in-memory) before booting into it.

The MSR (Microsoft Reserved) partition is only used on GPT installations. I'm not sure what this is for.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-biosmbr-based-hard-drive-partitions

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions

Comment: you write "There are two different partitions that you might be talking about (System and MSR)."  <-- well, looks the one you call System(so, with the MBR disks),, is called System Reserved   https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xcwmr.png

Comment: @barlop That is just the partition label. You can name a partition anything. Different vendors use different partition scripts. The sample script from Microsoft labels this partition "System". https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-deployment-sample-scripts-sxs

Comment: the reserved partition is for storing [dynamic disk data](https://superuser.com/a/942078/241386) or anything that needs some disk space in the future [*The UEFI specification does not allow hidden sectors on GPT-formatted disks. Microsoft reserves a chunk of disk space using this MSR partition type, to provide an alternative data storage space for such software components which previously may have used hidden sectors on MBR formatted disks*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Reserved_Partition)

Comment: are they both 100MB?